# Left Join Specific Columns From Two Different Tables Using Alias

Tags: mysql, sql, join, alias

I have two tables:

**toys**

item_id
int(4) unsigned

item_desc
varchar(100)

initial_quantity
int(4) unsigned

price
decimal(5,2)

*and*

**toy_purchases**

item_id
int(4) unsigned

customer_name
varchar(100)

quantity
int(4) unsigned

purchase_date
date

Only using aliases, how would I list out only the item description from the toys table, along with only the customer_name and purchase_date (whether or not they exist) from toy_purchases.

I have tried the following:

```
select b.book_name 
from books as b 
left outer join bc.customer_name, bc.purchase_date 
from book_customers as bc on b.bookid=bc.itemid;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use left join ? There is an example http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: You are probably after: `SELECT t.item_desc AS Description, tp.customer_name AS Customer, tp.purchase_date AS DatePurchased FROM toys t LEFT JOIN toy_purchases tp ON t.item_id = tp.item_id`

Comment: @Linger I've tried the following if you can understand my logic here. select b.book_name from books as b left outer join bc.customer_name, bc.purchase_date from book_customers as bc on b.bookid=bc.itemid;   I need to use aliases where possible and only display the columns I mentioned. item_desc from toys and customer_name, purchase_date from toy_purchases

Comment: It's high time, you should consider learning about basic SQL syntax.

Comment: @Rahul I'm in the process of learning basic SQL syntax and this was a quiz question. I was never shown how to use aliases selecting only certain columns from BOTH tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the proper syntax for a query.  I think you are actually after:

```
SELECT t.item_desc AS Description, 
       tp.customer_name AS Customer, 
       tp.purchase_date AS DatePurchased 
FROM toys t 
LEFT JOIN toy_purchases tp ON t.item_id = tp.item_id
```

Comment: No problem, I would recommend buying a book on sql and reading through it.

Comment: Take a few hours and read through this before going further.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: @kzarns, that's a awful source. if you really want to point OP to some online learning resource then point him to MySQL doc or SQLZoo or SQLCourse but never to w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

To left join table1 with only specific columns from table2 using an alias we can do this:

```sql
            SELECT 
              A.*, B.aThingIWant1, B.aThingIWant2
            FROM table1 A

            LEFT JOIN table2 B
            ON A.id = B.application_id
```

Notice above you can use columns that are not selected when joining tables.

To join 3 tables you could do this:
This joins all of table A with all of table B
then it joins columnIWant from table C

```sql
            SELECT 
              A.*, B.*, C.columnIWant
            FROM table1 A

            LEFT JOIN table2 B
            ON A.id = B.application_id

            LEFT JOIN table3 C
            ON A.id = C.application_id
```